# Serverless middleware Error: Cannot find module 'notifications-dev-findLead'

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless

After a lot of tries I'm surrendering and asking this

this is my serverless.yml

```
console: true
service: notifications
frameworkVersion: '3'
useDotenv: true

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-middleware

custom:
  middleware:
    folderName: middleware  # defaults to '.middleware'
    cleanFolder: false            # defaults to 'true'
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  versionFunctions: false
  region: ${opt:region, 'sa-east-1'}

functions:
  findAllLeads:
    handler: src/server.findAllLeads
    events:
      - http:
          path: leads
          method: get
          cors: true # <-- CORS!
  findLead:
    handler: src/server.findLead
    middleware:
      pre:
        - middleware/middleware.myF
    events:
      - http:
          path: leads/{id}
          method: get
          cors:
            origin: "*"
  createLead:
    handler: src/server.createLead
    middleware:
      pre:
        - middleware/middleware.myF
    events:
      - http:
          path: leads
          method: post
          cors: true # <-- CORS!
```

and my project strcucture is something like

```
middleware/ 
    middleware.ts
src/
    servers.ts // with handlers
```

and my middleware.ts is

```
// export const middleware = (event: any) => {
//   console.log(event.body);
// };
export const myF = (event) => {
// will do some logic if I make it work
  console.log(event.body);
};
```

and ALL im getting is

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

as a response and in the logs
[image: description]

Does anyone know how to fix this?